# SoapUI request modifying "@" to "%40"

Tags: api, encoding, request, soapui, urlencode

I'm using SoapUI to automate tests against my companies APIs. I've successfully setup and run dozens of these cases.
This tyme, I'm getting an error which, after exhaustive tracking down, I've found is due to our APIs requiring the "@" char itself rather than the URL friendly "%40" substitution.

The post request I want is structured like this:

```
https://<endpoint>.com/<resource>?<param>&email_address@example.com
```

And what I'm seeing made is:

```
https://<endpoint>.com/<resource>?<param>&email_address%40example.com
```

How can I enforce SoapUI to use the char itself?
I've tried setting headers, media type and representations (though possibly not through all permutations).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Disable Encoding](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/reference/method-window.html) for the parameter.

Comment: Thanks! That was a little buried, but I found it.
Sadly, however, it seems that this wasn't my problem.

I may need to create another ticket here, but:
When I execute my calls from the Script it fails. When I execute the call from the Resource itself, it passes. It was between these two calls that I found the "@" and "%40" differences.
Now that is resolved, but the issue persists.

The raw requests are identical. But execution from Script fails and from the Resource passes.

Comment: @EliLyonhart What version of SoapUI? I know there were bugs with URL encoding. Just as a check, can you try the same with old version of SoapUI, like version 4.6.4 https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui/soapui-os-older-versions.html

Comment: Thank you again.
For posterity, your solution was perfect.
The problem turned out to be the speed with which my calls were being made. I had to put a (5 full seconds!) rest in so that my first call could be resolved before launching the second.

So, in the end it was a very frustrating solution to a problem which didn't have to do with soapUI in the first place.

Comment: @EliLyonhart At least you're up and running again! :)